# Relative Links Lead to no SSL?

Tags: html, css, ssl, hyperlink, server

I have a SSL certificate and it works perfectly when I try to access the website using https://www.website.com. But whenever I click a relative link on the site, it will lead to a page of the site without SSL.

For example the link is

```
<a href="/about">Click</a>
```

I'm expecting to reach https://www.website.com/about but instead it takes me to website.com/about.

Why doesn't it work? I have tried Googling and found using absolute pathways (which I'm trying to avoid for now) and using "//", which doesn't work either. I'm using Hostinger as server provider if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

On the Hostinger site, there is an article about how to configure your site to force all traffic to https using server side redirect rules

https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/ssl/forcing-https

Comment: Thanks for the link. I followed the tutorial step by step but now I can't reach the website because "too many redirects".